# Getting VS2015 to work with arcpy

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio-2015, gis

I am taking a course on programming ESRI's ArcGIS using Python.  Although the course content shows us how to work with various IDE's, I would like to do my homework in Visual Studio 2015 (Community Edition).  But I am having trouble getting it to work on my laptop and would like some advice.

I have successfully installed ArcGIS.  I have successfully run some Python scripts which include the use of the arcpy module.  One IDE that recognizes arcpy, pycharm, shows me path information about the environment. For example, PyCharm's External Libraries window shows C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3 .

In Visual Studio, when I open a .py file known to run under the other interpreters, the IDE marks import arcpy as an unknown package.  So in Visual Studio I am attempting to set up a new Python Enviornment, "ArcGIS-enabled", to get it to recognize that package.  So far I have not been successful.  Here I what I have tried so far:

I set

```
Prefix Path = C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\
Interpreter Path = C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\python.exe
Windowed Interpreter = C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\pythonw.exe
Library Path = C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib
```

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Try this - https://cindygeodev.wordpress.com/2015/09/28/enable-intellisense-in-pyt-files-in-ptvs/ , found from: https://andreashoogeveen.wordpress.com/2016/01/28/arcpy-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: KHibma, thanks for the link.  I looked at it and it did what it said and that worked.  If you would like to expand on it and offer it as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS probably just needs a minute or two to recognize/load the arcpy package. So after importing arcpy, just let it sit.

Further to that, if you want to add PYT (PythonToolboxes) as a supported type to edit, do:
**Tools** > **Options** > **Text Editor** > **File Extension**. Type **pyt** into the text box and choose **Python Editor** from the dropdown list.

[Reference link](https://cindygeodev.wordpress.com/2015/09/28/enable-intellisense-in-pyt-files-in-ptvs/)